# Linux: Piping output to unique files

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, command

I have a folder filed with hundreds of text files which I want to run a Linux command called `mint`. This command outputs a text value which I want stored in unique files, one for each file I have in the folder. Is there a way to run the command using the `*` character to represent all my input files, while still piping the output to a file that is unique from each other file?

Example:
`$ mint * > uniqueFile.krn`

Comment: you may try "for file in  *; do mint $file > $file.krn; done"

Comment: However, if you have for example `file1` and `file1.krn` as input files, you will get an unwanted overwrite. It seems likely you verified that there are no `.krn` files, but for safety, if using bash, you could set noclobber: `set -C`.

Comment: Make a copy and try `parallel 'mint {} > {}.krn' ::: *`

Comment: `mint $file > int_$file` is actually a bit buggy, if any of your filenames contain spaces. Quotes are important: `mint "$file" > "int_$file"`

Comment: BTW, answers don't belong in questions. If you want to add an answer, *add it as an answer*. If you don't think you could get credit/rep for it (because, in this case, it came from a comment), mark it "Community Wiki".

Comment: ...keeping answers separate from questions means that a good question can be upvoted without also implying that the OP's own answer is a good one; a bad self-answer can be *downvoted* without asserting that the question is bad; etc. It further means that those answers are on the "same playing field" with all other answers, rather than getting special status.

Answer (score 0):

With the bugs fixed and caveats closed:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^ - bash, not sh, for [[ ]] support

for f in *.krn; do
  [[ $f = *.krn ]] && continue # skip files already ending in .krn
  mint "$f" >"$f.krn"
done
```

Or, with a prefix:

```
for f in *; do
  [[ $f = int_* ]] && continue
  mint "$f" >"int_$f"
done
```

You can also avoid recreating hashes that already exist unless the source file changed:

```
for f in *; do

  # don't hash hash files
  [[ $f = int_* ]] && continue

  # if a non-empty hash file exists, and is newer than our source file, don't hash again
  [[ -s "int_$f" && "int_$f" -nt "$f" ]] && continue

  # ...if we got through the above conditions, then go ahead with creating a hash
  mint "$f" >"int_$f"
done
```

To explain:

- `test -s filename` is true only if a file by the given name exists and is non-empty
- `test file1 -nt file2` is true only if both files exist, and `file1` is newer than `file2`.
- `[[ ]]` is a ksh-extended shell syntax derived from that for the `test` command, adding support for pattern-matching tests (ie. `[[ $string = *.txt ]]` will be true only if `$string` expands to a value ending in `.txt`), and relaxing quoting rules (it's safe to write `[[ -s $f ]]`, but `test -s "$f"` needs the quotes to work with all possible filenames).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions! Shiping's solution worked great, I just appended a prefix to the file name. Like so:

```
$ for file in * ; do mint $file > int_$file ; done
```

*Self-answer moved from question and flagged Community Wiki; see [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que)*

Comment: This has some bugs. For instance, it'll create files with names like `int_int_foo` files if you run it more than once, and it won't correctly handle files with spaces in its names.